# Execute Query Within Wordpress Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I have a query that I would like to wrap in a shortcode function so I can call it in a post or page. It should pull 4 posts as follows. `trim_title()` is another custom function which limits the title to a specific character count. I have verified that the query (with the loop) works when I insert it directly into the php template, but I want to be able to include it in the editor as a shortcode.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
function homepage_newsfeed($atts) {
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        echo '<a href="';
        the_permalink();
        echo '">';
        trim_title();
        echo '</a>'; 
        echo '<div class="newspostdate">';
        the_time('F j, Y');
        echo '</div>';
        endif;
        endwhile;
}

add_shortcode ( 'newsfeed', 'homepage_newsfeed');
```

This is within the loop. I also tried including the loop in the function like so:

```
function homepage_newsfeed($atts) {
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo '<a href="';
        the_permalink();
        echo '">';
        trim_title();
        echo '</a>'; 
        echo '<div class="newspostdate">';
        the_time('F j, Y');
        echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
        endif;
}

add_shortcode ( 'newsfeed', 'homepage_newsfeed');
```

I've also tried using return rather than echo like so:

```
function homepage_newsfeed($atts) {
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        return '<a href="';
        the_permalink();
        return '">';
        trim_title();
        return '</a>'; 
        return '<div class="newspostdate">';
        the_time('F j, Y');
        return '</div>';
        endwhile;
        endif;
}

add_shortcode ( 'newsfeed', 'homepage_newsfeed');
```

These are just a few of my attempts among many others. I have done a lot of searching to see how to execute php inside of a shortcode, but most of my search results find articles referencing using `do_shortcode(`) to use a shortcode in PHP. I appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It's fine generating a new query, but you shouldn't be using the functions starting with `the_` to access it, they are for use in "The Loop", which you are not.  Setting $wp_query to override the primary query is ill-advised, and you would need to call `global $wp_query;` at the top of the function anyhow to override it.  It's not necessary anyhow, look at the [usage of WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` returns the value, which is what you need, but also exits the function.
Also in WP you have a `get_` prefixed version of your helper functions, which also returns a value instead of directly echoing it.

so what you might want to try is something like:

```
function myfunction(){
    $string = 'lets'; 
    $string .= ' build some string ';
    $string .= get_the_permalink();
    return $string;
}
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php